# Vue perform async update in parent component on child emit

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I have a component that displays data using various chart child components, for this i want to do clientside filtering of the chartdata in the parent component. I have another child component handling the filtering, it sends an event to the parent when a filter has been applied and the parent will re-calculate the data and send to the chart child components.

Currently the re-calculation takes too long when a filter has been applied, and there is a freeze in the UI that i'm trying to get rid of.

This is a pseudolike code sample of how it currently looks:

```
export default {
    name: "reportingView",
    components: {
        chartA,
        chartB,
        filtering
    },
    data() {
        return {
            chartAData, //used as prop to chartA
            chartBData //used as prop to chartA
        }
    },
    methods: {
        filterChangedEvent(e) {
            this.calculateChartData()
        },
        async calculateChartData() {
            //Calculate data and update chartAData and chartBData
            console.log("calculation done");
        }
    },
    updated() {
        console.log("parent updated");
    }
}

export default {
    name: "filtering",
    data() {
        return {
            appliedFilters
        }
    }
    methods: {
        filterChanged() {
            this.this.$emit("filterChanged", this.appliedFilters);
        }
    }
    updated() {
        console.log("child updated");
    }
}
```

I want the filter component to re-render as soon as something as done, then emit the change to the parent components, then the parent component should recalculate the data async and then re-render the UI once it's completed.

I want the log to be:
"child upadted"
"calculation done"
"parent updated"

but im getting
"calculation done"
"child updated"
"parent updated", and the UI is frozen during calcuation

How can i implement async updateds in parent when child emits an event?

Comment: Use computed properties if you want them to cause rerender on change: https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/computed.html

Comment: That won't solve the problem, if the computed property takes 2sec to calculate there will still be a UI freeze.